# Registering (Signing Up) with Passport in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Using the examples for passport-local, I got the sign in to work. There's no documentation on how to register users.

I'd like to give users an "email" and "password" field that they can use to sign up for the site. How can I do this? Any reason this isn't documented? Is it really obvious or something?

Answer (score 0):

actually this has been explained too many times ..
if the table schema you are using is `User` then just ,create a new record in the database.

```
var newUser = new User();
newUser({username: req.body.username , password : req.body.password});
newUser.save(function(doc , error){ 
    if(error) console.log('user is not saved');
    res.send(200);
    })
```